# How do I use the selected property to selected parameters of an Insert query with drop down list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am using a grid, drop down box and button to insert information of an order into an order table on sqlserver (in visual studio - all tables have records except the order table) - I am not sure how to incorporate all three in order to update the table though. When the logged in user clicks on their selected item - chooses a pharmacy and clicks the confirm button this should update.

Grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"  >
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName="UpdateMedicine" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MedicineId") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Purpose" HeaderText="Purpose" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Instrcutions" HeaderText="Instructions" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code for grid:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "UpdateMedicine" Then


        Dim MedicineID As Integer = Integer.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())

    End If

End Sub
```

Dropdown - button .click

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropPharm" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlPharm" DataTextField="Pharmname" DataValueField="Pharmname"></asp:DropDownList>

   <br />
   <br />


  <asp:Button ID="btnconfirm" runat="server" Text="Confirm" />
```

Code for button:

```
Protected Sub btnconfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnconfirm.Click

    Dim strPatientId As Integer = Session("PatientId").ToString
    Dim strMedicineId As Integer
    Dim strDoctorId As Integer
    Dim strPharmacyId As Integer
    Dim strDateOrdered As Date



    Dim query As String = String.Empty
    query &= "INSERT INTO Order_pres (PatientId, MedicineId, PharmacyId, "
    query &= "                     DoctorId, [Date Ordered])  "
    query &= "VALUES (@PatientId,@MedicineId, @PharmacyId, @DoctorId, @DateOrdered)"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection("SurgeryConnectionString"), _
          comm As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
        With comm.Parameters

            .Add("@PatientId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(strPatientId)
            .Add("@MedicineId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(strMedicineId)
            .Add("@PharmacyId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(strPharmacyId)
            .Add("@DoctorId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(strDoctorId)
            .Add("@DateOrdered", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(strDateOrdered)
        End With

        Try
            conn.Open()
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            lblconfirm.Text() = "Order Placed"
        Catch ex As SqlException
            lblnoconfirm.Text() = "Order not placed"
        End Try
    End Using

End Sub
```

I have been stuck on this for quite some time if any one could give me some direction or an example I would appreciate it very much:)  - thank you

Comment: I'm confused by your wording.  Do you just need to know how to get values from what the user selects in the datagridview and dropdownlist?

Comment: @lamelemon hi there, sorry I have worded this badly but yes how to I use the selection on the grid and the selection of pharmacy on the drop down to insert these values when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you're wanting.
To get the value or text from the dropdownlist use:

```
someVariable = DropPharm.SelectedItem.Text
someVariable = DropPharm.SelectedItem.Value
```

To get the selected row's cell values use:

```
someVariable = GridView1.Rows(GridView1.SelectedIndex).Cells(yourColumnIndex).Value
```

Use this to set your variables in the btnconfirm_Click sub.

Make `MedicineID` a class level variable so declare it outside all the subs but inside of your class so you can access it's value in another sub.  Then in your btn click sub:

```
Dim strMedicineId As Integer = MedicineID
```

Then do an `IF EXISTS` in your query so you can update it if it already exists in the database with something like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Order_pres WHERE MedicineID=@MedicineID AND PatientID=@PatientID AND PharmacyID=@PharmacyID AND.....)
    UPDATE Order_press SET (…) WHERE MedicineID=@MedicineID AND....
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Order_pres (…) VALUES (..)
```

Comment: Hi @lamelemon ! thank you so much for taking time to answer this - one query though   - this is for my grid row command - `Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "UpdateMedicine" Then


        Dim MedicineID As Integer = Integer.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())

    End If`        - is this incorrect?

Comment: @laurajs Not 100% on that.  Can you try debugging to see what it returns?

Comment: it does return the value of the medicine Id. see when the user logs in under a session the grid displays their medicine (On the database ther is a Patient and medicine able but I have also created a link table which holds patient and medicine Id)  the grid does display and the e.command recognises which medicine has been selected

Comment: but from my on code above I want to ensure after the medicine has been selected and pharmacy selected from the drop down and the button is clicked this updates the order tavle (Order_pres)

Comment: @laurajs I added some more info.  Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: thank you so much for your kind help - I am having some issues with my code to get the information on the grid again I am trying to resolve - but when I do I will test this :)